# Bound off-heap memory consumption in ksqlDB

Tags: ksqldb

I'm trying to bound somehow off-heap memory consumption in ksqlDB server. I found an article about this: https://www.confluent.io/blog/bounding-ksqldb-memory-usage. In first approach, I set KSQL_OPTS:

```
    -Dksql.streams.rocksdb.config.setter=io.confluent.ksql.rocksdb.KsqlBoundedMemoryRocksDBConfigSetter
```

but I got:

```
[2020-11-16 07:25:15,848] ERROR Failed to start KSQL (io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain:60)
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value io.confluent.ksql.rocksdb.KsqlBoundedMemoryRocksDBConfigSetter for configuration rocksdb.config.setter: Class io.confluent.ksql.rocksdb.KsqlBoundedMemoryRocksDBConfigSetter could not be found.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(ConfigDef.java:728)
    at io.confluent.ksql.config.ConfigItem$Resolved.parseValue(ConfigItem.java:125)
    at io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlConfig.lambda$resolveStreamsConfig$2(KsqlConfig.java:693)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265)
    at io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlConfig.resolveStreamsConfig(KsqlConfig.java:693)
    at io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlConfig.lambda$applyStreamsConfig$0(KsqlConfig.java:675)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$EntrySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1746)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlConfig.applyStreamsConfig(KsqlConfig.java:678)
    at io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlConfig.buildStreamingConfig(KsqlConfig.java:701)
    at io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlConfig.<init>(KsqlConfig.java:738)
    at io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlConfig.<init>(KsqlConfig.java:708)
    at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.main(KsqlServerMain.java:50)
```

I also tried to set this parameter in `ksqldb-server.properties` but result was the same. I'm using docker image: `confluentinc/ksqldb-server:0.9.0`. Is it correct way to do this in such a way or I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

The ksqldb-rocksdb-config-setter jar isn't included in the Docker image. You can pull the jar in from confluent's maven repository.

See: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/6644